# Unknown Component: apex:emailPublisher

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, casefeed

I'm trying to write a simple VF page using below code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
    <apex:emailPublisher entityId="{!case.id}"
                         toAddresses="{!case.contact.email}"/>
</apex:page>
```

When I try to save, I receive the error:

> Error: Unknown component apex:emailPublisher

- I'm using API Version 39.0, and documentation shows this came-out in API=25.
- I have Case Feed enabled and working.
- None of the Case Feed components are showing the VF editor

Comment: where are you writing the code developer console/eclipse/directly on the VF page UI ?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_emailPublisher.htm?search_text=apex:emailPublisher): *This component can only be used in organizations that have Case Feed and Email-to-Case enabled. Ext JS versions less than 3 should not be included on pages that use this component.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adrian!

His answer solved my question.

> From the documentation: This component can only be used in organizations that have Case Feed and Email-to-Case enabled. Ext JS versions less than 3 should not be included on pages that use this component. – Adrian Larson♦ 22 hours ago